# Enchanting Items above 37%

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've gotten my Enchantment up to 100, and my smithing up to 100, So I *was* wearing Vampire armour which allowed 125% magicka regen, which I thought was pretty awesome.  Anyway,  I thought well wouldn't it be nice to look cool and also have the armour AND regen, but it turns out I can't do that?

After all this work to level up, I disenchant my Vampire Armour, make daedric armour, enchant it with greater soul, and only get 37%!! What kind of crap is that?

How can I make enchantments like the enchantments that are found in the game items?

Comment: 37% of what?  Magicka regen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall value of your enchantment can be affected by several things, such as your skill perks and any stat effects you have such as potions or equipment with enchant boosts. Also if you want to achieve the best enchantments, you should use more powerful soul gems, either Grand soul gems (grand) or Black soul gems (grand).

However even with these the in game items often have higher enchantments that ones you can create unfortunately. Although there are ways that you can get around this by using exploits to boost your enchantments. Hope this helps!

For more information check out: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting